# SQL Server : deleting rows by month name

Tags: sql-server

How do I delete by month name instead of date number?

I would like to use 'April' instead of '04'

This is as far as i have gotten, but it still does not work.

```
DELETE * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, myColumn) LIKE 'April'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    DATENAME(MONTH,myColumn) LIKE 'April'
```

since SQL-SERVER 2008 you can use `DATENAME()` function to extract it from a date.  I personally would still prefer the integers but since you asked....

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `DATENAME`, see documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

In your case, it would be:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE DATENAME(MONTH,myColumn) LIKE 'April'
```